# Control panel: access denied on second site

Tags: control-panel, multi-site-manager

After updating to Expressionengine 2.9 and MSM 2.1.7 the client admins are not able to switch to the second site anymore (same permissions as on the first site), superadmins have access.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: We have the same problem with a site of a client. Is this a bug? Please help me! Thanks in advance!!! Grtz,
Martijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug, with a fix: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20529/msm-site-switching-not-working-for-non-superadmin